# Raspberry Pi Backup Battery Hat V1.2 battery level

Tags: raspbian, battery

My question is about `Raspberry Pi Backup Battery Hat V1.2` specification.
Is it possible to see somehow level of battery discharging (% of battery charge) by using the operation linux system like Raspbian? I did not bought this shield yet, and before i do that, i need to be sure that board has `battery level` feature. This question is regarding to `Raspberry Pi Backup Battery Hat V1.2` owners mostly.

[image]

Comment: Link goes to a 404 page. You'd be better off asking the manufacturers.

Comment: i don't speak chineeze to ask manufacturers :D